# Image shows in the iPad simulator but not the device

Tags: xcode, image, ipad, ios-simulator

I have a small png that I am adding to a view which I am pretty sure I had working previously but suddenly stopped working on the iPad itself while continuing to work fine on the iPad simulator.

Here is the code I am using to add the image to the view...

```
  UIImageView *bottomResizer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"resizeLine.png"]];
  bottomResizer.center = CGPointMake(bottomResizer.center.x, bottomResizer.center.y+self.frame.size.height-12);
  bottomResizer.tag = 301;
  [self addSubview:bottomResizer]; 
  [bottomResizer release];
```

This occurs in a UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan event. The following code in removes the image in a touchesEnded event without any errors even though you cannot see it.

```
 NSArray *subViews = [self subviews];
 int count = [subViews count];
 for (int i =count-1; i>=0; i--) {
     if([[subViews objectAtIndex:i] tag] == 301) {
         [[subViews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];

     }
 }
```

I don't think it is anything I changed in my code since it works in the simulator. Not sure where to look next for the problem. I have reset the simulator to see if it would break after a reset. I have also cleaned the project.

Thanks.

John

Comment: Double check to make sure resizeLine.png is not corrupt. Sometimes images can get slightly corrupted, and still work on the simulator, but don't on the device. Try inserting a new image and see if you get the same issue.

Comment: If I use another image it works fine. Thanks, the image is corrupted some how. See my comment to logancautrell's answer. Any suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a breakpoint AFTER this line `UIImageView *bottomResizer = [[UIImageView alloc]...`

Then on the console "po [bottomResizer image]"

If it is nil then either the resource is not getting copied correctly into the bundle OR you could have a corrupt image that the device cannot load.

Comment: Sure enough that the image is nil on the ipad but not the simulator. Any suggestion on how to resolve the issue. After reading your post I opened the png in a drawing program and saved it to a new file to replace the one in my project. I also reset the iPad... No Joy.

Comment: That did it! I converted to a gif and back to a png. Thanks!!

Comment: If (re)converting image formats and back again doesnt do the trick.  And you know your image isnt getting copied to bundle, yet your file is added to the target and present in "copy bundle resources" and returns nil in your test, how might you go about fixing that?

Comment: Remove the file from the project and re add it.